# Django import-export display manytomany as a name instead of ids when exporting to csv

Tags: django, django-import-export

How do I display a manytomany column as a list of names instead of ids using `Django import-export`?

Currently my models and resources.py looks like this and returns a csv with a list of ids for the `country` column:

**models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False,
                            blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**resources.py**

```
from import_export import resources,fields
from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget
from .models import Species, Country

class SpeciesResource(resources.ModelResource):
    country=fields.Field(attribute='country', widget=ManyToManyWidget(Country), column_name='Country')
    name = fields.Field(attribute='name', column_name='Name')
    class Meta:
        model = Species
        fields =('name','country')
        export_order = fields
```

Comment: Try to change `fields` in Meta: `fields =('name','country__name')`

Comment: @SergeyPugach that just turns the column blank, I also tried `def dehydrate_country(self, sp)`: sp.country.name and also blank

Comment: try: `widget=ManyToManyWidget(Country, field='name')` and return `country` to Meta. as `pk` is in `field` by default.

Comment: @SergeyPugach ok that worked please post a response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add field you need in widget:

```
widget=ManyToManyWidget(Country, field='name')
```